# How can I make intro js work with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intro.js

I am trying to use [introJs](http://introjs.com/) with React but it seems not to work. How can I make it work? Can you give me an example?

Comment: What does that mean _it doesn't work_?

Comment: Great alternative library that is fully integrated with React is React Joyride https://gilbarbara.github.io/react-joyride/

Comment: Searching something related, finished doing [this library](https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour)

Comment: Since then, a package was developed for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/intro.js-react

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following to your `index.html`

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/intro.js/2.3.0/introjs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/intro.js/2.3.0/intro.min.js"></script>
```

Now, call `introJs().start()` inside `componentDidMount`

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    introJs().start()
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <a href='http://google.com/' data-intro='Hello step one!'>one</a>
      <a href='http://google.com/' data-intro='Hello step two!'>two</a>
      <a href='http://google.com/' data-intro='Hello step three!'>three</a>
      <a href='http://google.com/' data-intro='Hello step four!'>four</a>
      </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
a{
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/intro.js/2.3.0/introjs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/intro.js/2.3.0/intro.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I almost did the same but it wouldn't work. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: This gives me intro is undefined

Comment: Since then, a package was developed for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/intro.js-react

Answer (score 15):

You can just treat it like any other npm module you'd add to your React app.

1. Install using npm:

   `npm install intro.js --save`
2. Import the module and css into the component where you want to use them:

   `import introJs from 'intro.js';
   import 'intro.js/introjs.css';`
3. When the component mounts call the necessary function:

   `componentDidMount() {
     introJs().start();
   }`
4. Add steps to the jsx as you normally would with html:

   `data-intro='Hello step one!'`

One odd thing that was happening to me was that some the css in the `intro.js` / `intro.min.js` wasn't operating as I expected. I had to jump into those files an tweak the `opacity` on the  `.introjs-helperLayer` selector and the `z-index` on `.introjs-fixParent` but that could have been an edge case just for me.

Comment: Since then, a package was developed for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/intro.js-react